# Hiding shapes inside following slides

Tags: vba, powerpoint, basic

This is probably very simple. I have 10 slides each one with lots of shapes. Each slide has an shape called "AAA":

- I go to slideshow mode
- I click shape AAA in any slide. Shape AAA inside the current slide dissapears.
- All "shapes A" from the *following* slides dissapear too.
- All shapes *different* from shape AAA, remain unchanged.

How can I code that? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please tell us how you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First i defined V50 as a public variable then i used this:

(i used an animation to vanish the button and set this macro to run when clicking the AAA shape)

> Sub LL50()
>
> V50 = 1
>
> End Sub

Then i found out this piece of code to run on slide change:

> Sub OnSlideChange()
>
> ```
> Dim i As Integer
> i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
> If i <> 1 Then Exit Sub
> ```
>
> If V50=1 then
>
> ActivePresentation.Slides(ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideNumber +
> 1).Shapes("AAA").Visible = False
>
> End if
>
> End sub